# Which folders need to writable for Magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to install a new extension, but I just get "Warning: Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions." I have 777'd the whole of my Magento install and the warning goes.

But the extension still does not install, the page just reloads with no changes.

Is there a larger issue here?

Also which folders **need** to be writable by Apache and which do not. I cannot seem to find a definite list of permission requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For magento to function you need write permissions on `var` and `media` folders.
To install an extension...well..you need write permissions where the extension is trying to add files. That may depend from one extension to an other.
I would say give write permissions on everything, install the extension then reset the permissions and allow write only on `var` and `media`

Edit: I believe you also need write permissions to the `temp` directory as well.

Comment: thanks for this, but 777-ing those directories hasn't helped. I think there is a larger issue as even when everything is 777'd no extensions install.